# Proving $\sin 6\theta \cos4\theta + \cos4\theta\sin2\theta = {(\cos 2\theta \tan 8\theta)\over \sec 8\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to prove the following:
$$\sin 6\theta \cos4\theta + \cos4\theta\sin2\theta = {(\cos 2\theta \tan 8\theta)\over \sec 8\theta}$$
How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $$2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B),$$

$$2\sin B\cos A=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B),$$

and then

$$\sin C+\sin D=2\sin\frac{C+D}2\cos\frac{C-D}2$$

finally $$\frac{\tan y}{\sec y}=\frac{\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}}{\frac1{\cos y}}=\sin y$$